# When does this integral exist?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, bounds-of-integration

I try to learn about Sobolev-spaces defined with tempered distribution.

> *I would like to understand for what  $s\in\mathbb{R}$ does*
>   $$\int (1+|\xi|^2)^s \mathrm d\xi\,, \qquad \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ 
>   *exist?*

I think this could be helpful to understand Sobolev-spaces in this context.
Can anybody help me with this? I am thankful for every help.

Comment: You can use `\quad` and `\qquad` for horizontal spacing, too=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function is continuous everywhere, hence you need to study what happens when $|\xi|\to\infty$. By comparison with $|\xi|^{2s}$ you deduce easily that for $2s+n < 0$ the integral converges and for $2s+n\ge0$ the integral diverges. Polar coordinates help, too.